# Macro - countif function checking if the range "contains" the criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which does the countif function checking the criteria from the column B in arange in a column A. Both (range and criteria) might have different size, so the macro goes until the last cell populated. However, it checks exactly the same matches. I would like to transform it to check if the range contains the criateria. For instance, if the criteria is "Manager" and in the range we have "Marketing Manager", I would like to count it. Below you can find the screenshot of the excel file and the code of my macro.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Macro Code:**

```
Sub Countif_Until_LastRow()

Dim lastRowColumnB As Long
lastRowColumnB = Range("B65000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRowColumnB
Cells(i, 3) = Application.CountIf(Range("A:A"), Cells(i, 2))
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cells(i, 3) = Application.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "*" & Cells(i, 2) & "*")
```

***(star) works like a wild char